# Un plat si délicieux qu'il faut le manger caché

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Bonjour.  Un ami américain est venu en vacances en France et il m'a dit qu'il a gouté à un plat exquis, au point que la légende voudrait qu'il faille le manger caché (des yeux de Dieu ?).
Ne parlant pas français, il ne se rappelait plus du nom. Et malheureusement cette légende ne me dit rien.

P.S : cette question diffère un peu des autres (souvent grammaire ou incompréhension de vocabulaire) mais quoi de plus naturel quand il s'agit du palais que de s'adresser à un forum sur notre langue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ca sont les ortolans que l'on doit manger avec un linge sur la tête.

Je ne connais pas l'origine de cette coutume, mais on peut lire la description d'un repas d'ortolans dans une nouvelle de Maupassant. Ma mémoire me joue des tours quant au titre de cette nouvelle.

Par ailleurs François Miterrand était grand amateur. On peut lire une description d'un repas avec une illustration [ici](http://www.pileface.com/sollers/article.php3?id_article=611).

*Extrait :*

> « Georges-Marc Benamou nous apprend que, pour son repas d’adieu, sept jours avant sa mort, François Mitterrand, en compagnie de ses fidèles, a mangé des ortolans.
>
> Au milieu du repas, les invités, les hommes et l’ancien président de la République glissent la tête sous une serviette : "C’est une dizaine de taches blanches, une drôle d’assemblée de fantômes qui suçotent, pendant que les femmes parlent à voix basse... Il faut prendre la tête de l’ortolan brûlant dans sa bouche et la broyer, la faire craquer franchement sous les dents. »

Comment: Oui, j'allais l'écrire et ajouter que la coutume (plutôt qu'obligation - ton emploi du mot *devoir*-) de mettre une serviette sur la tête vient du fait qu'on préfère se cacher parce qu'on le met **en entier** dans sa bouche tout dégoulinant de graisse et parfois on doit recracher quelque morceau un peu plus dur, ce qui n'est pas très ragoûtant.  La légende dit que c'est pour se cacher des yeux de Dieu, mais pas parce que c'est bon, mais par honte de manger une créature si si belle et délicate.

Comment: Tout à fait hors sujet sur ce site : les ortolans sont une espèce protégée depuis 1979 selon [Courrier International](http://www.courrierinternational.com/article/2014/10/23/la-guerre-de-l-ortolan-est-relancee)et quand on a l'occasion d'en manger de nos jours il s'agit de braconnage.

Comment: I’m sure the legend existed long before the ever lovable Kermitterrand called himself  «Dieu» on *Le Bébête show* but one could still perhaps wonder which dieu were Tonton’s guests  hiding from and maybe  even if He was just hiding from Himself?

Comment: Traditionnellement « [...] on les garde dans l’obscurité [dans une petite boite noire] pendant vingt et un jours, parfois après les avoir aveuglés [lire après leur avoir crevé les yeux], ce qui les pousse à se gaver de millet et de raisin [...] Une fois qu’ils ont triplé de volume, ils sont noyés dans de l’armagnac [...] ». On aimerait voir les convives avec une boîte noire décorée des motifs de vignes sur le visage et dans laquelle on pourrait insérer l'ortolan vivant et de visu voir qui se gave de quoi ; la gastronomie traditionnelle serait bien vivante !